# Guard-Uglify throws "only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed"

Tags: ruby, guard, uglifyjs

I'm trying to uglify javascript using guard but i get following errors:

> ERROR - Guard::Uglify failed to achieve its , exception was:
>   [#] JSON::GeneratorError: only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed
>   [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:216:in `generate'
>   [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:216:in`generate'
>   [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:352:in `dump'
>   [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:53:in`block (2 levels) in compile'
>   [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:51:in `sub!'
>   [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:51:in`block in compile'
>   [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:47:in `tap'
>   [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:47:in`compile'

I'm using json 2.0.0(also tried with 1.8.0) and mutli-json 1.7.8(also tried 1.7.9)

**EDIT**

Code from Guardfile

```
guard 'uglify', :destination_file => "js/scripts.min.js" do
  watch 'js/scripts.min.js'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be linked to your javascript code not being formatted correctly.

If you have no clue of where the error may be, you could try to uglify only parts of your code separately until you find the one that throws the error.

Comment: The same thing happens when I compile empty file or something as simple as "var a = 1;"

Comment: Did my other answer help you ?

Comment: Actually I just switched over to Grunt. It turns out to be much easier and more intuitive but anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please show the code that makes the call to Guard's uglify.

It may be linked to the object you pass to Guard. => you need to read the file and parse it.

```
    JSON.parse(string or file read)
```